# How can I copy directories recursively with hardlinks with variables in bash?

Tags: cp, hard-link, ln

The operation I'm trying to do is take directory 1:

```
Dir1
    Dir A
        File A
    Dir B
        File B
```

Then use the `find` command to check every file in Dir 1 for whether or not they have an existing hardlink with something like:

```
find . -type f -links 1 -exec cp -al {} /path/to/Dir2/{} \;
```

Then I want to end up with:

```
Dir2
    Dir A
        File A (hardlink)
    Dir B
        File B (hardlink)
```

Right now I know how to find every non-hardlinked file in a directory, and place a hardlink to those files in a different directory, but I want to maintain the same directory structure when I make the new hardlinks. My current command would produce this:

```
Dir2
    File A (hardlink)
    File B (hardlink)
```

Say I'm looking at File B, and File B has only 1 link (has not been hardlinked), how would I refer to "Dir B" in order to copy that directory to the new directory? I wouldn't want "/Path/To/Dir B" just "Dir B".

Is there a way to accomplish this task in bash?

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with tools like `find`, and `mkdir`

In a bash file `.sh` dont forget to replace /path/to/Dir1 with the source directory path and /path/to/Dir2 with the destination directory path.

```
#!/bin/bash

src_dir="/path/to/Dir1"
dest_dir="/path/to/Dir2"

find "$src_dir" -type d -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' dir; do
    dest_subdir="${dir/$src_dir/$dest_dir}"
    
    mkdir -p "$dest_subdir"
    
    find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -links 1 -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
        cp -al "$file" "$dest_subdir"
    done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can accomplish this task in bash by using the `rsync` command instead of `cp` and modifying your `find` command to use variables. Here is an example command that should work for your needs:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Set source and destination directories
src_dir="Dir1"
dest_dir="Dir2"

# Use find to locate all files in source directory with only one link
find "$src_dir" -type f -links 1 | while read file; do
  # Get the directory name of the file and create the corresponding directory in the destination
  dir=$(dirname "$file")
  mkdir -p "$dest_dir/$dir"

  # Copy the file using rsync with the -l (hardlink) option
  rsync -av --link-dest="$src_dir" "$file" "$dest_dir/$file"
done
```